# Backbone - merge: true - option not changing UI

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, model, marionette

I noticed that when I write 
 
`collection1.add(model1);` --> UI changes fine. However, when I do 
`collection1.add(model1, {merge: true});` 
then `App.div1.currentView.collection.models` shows the changed model (in console) but UI does not change. 
 
I have no clue why? 
 
(Note1: I am using Marionette.js with Backbone) 
(Note2: App is the global Marionette object; div1 is a Marionette region in html)

Comment: At which event is executed rendering? "add"? Is `collection1` empty or have `model1` already?

Comment: Yes, its rendering at `add` event. `collection1` is not empty and has many models including `model1`. All I want is that when I use `merge: true`, `model1` should be updated with its new values in UI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked with `collection1.add(model1, {merge: true})` -

```
modelEvents: {
    "change": "render"
}

// "update": "render" did not work
```

Added ^^ to `Marionette.ItemView` which was responsible for `model1`.

Answer (score 1):

Event `add` is triggered only if new element is added to the collection. If `merge=false` (default behaviour) new element (probably) will be added (and You have collection with two identical attributes and different `cid`, `id`). With `merge=true` old element will be updated, and event `update` will be triggered.

`add` event will be triggered only if new element will be added.

`update` event will be triggered if element will be added, changed or removed.

Solution: render region on `update` event.